# Why does the average execution time for JAXB conversion to XML decrease as the number of elements in the list increase?

Tags: java, jaxb, jvm

I have a list containing some objects, which are converted to XML using JAXB. As I increase the number of records in the list, the time taken for conversion doesn't increase linearly. For 1 record, the time taken was .2 seconds; for 10000 records, the time taken was only 7 seconds. How did the average time for conversion decrease?

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
list.stream().forEach(Converter::toXml);
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Time taken for " + list.size() + " : " + (end-start));
```

P.S. I'm not including the time taken to populate the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JVM compiles code as it goes, the more you run it the faster it goes.  Normally full compilation doesn't start until you have performed 10000 method calls or iterations of a loop.  You can even see further optimisations after 100K iterations.

Unless you use a tool like JMH, I suggest you run the test repeatedly and ignore the first 2 seconds at least to give the JVM a chance to warm up. (BTW JMH ignores the first 20 seconds by default)